# Simple autocomplete with Ace Editor in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ace-editor

I'm working in XML and I'd like to provide autocomplete suggestions for the attributes for specific node types using AS3.

For example, if the user is has a cursor in the following node:

```
 <s:Button label="Hello World"/>
```

I'd like autocomplete to show "width, height, x, y".

I'm trying to get the node name and namespace and then give the editor a list of attributes that should appear in autocomplete.

I found similar questions but those are using a service call and a few that are out dated. I may delete this question if it is a duplicate.

Ace Editor for AS3 [here](https://github.com/monkeypunch3/flexcapacitor/blob/master/MainLibrary/src/com/flexcapacitor/controls/AceEditor.as).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, for AS3, it is a combination of items:

```
ace.setCompleters(null); // I'm removing existing autocomplete  
ace.addCompleter(codeCompleter); // adding my own

public var autoCompleteErrorMessage:String = "Nothing available";
public function codeCompleter(editor:Object, session:Object, position:Object, prefix:String, callback:Function):void {
    var row:int = position.row;
    var column:int = position.column;

    /*
    if (prefix.length === 0) { 
        callback(null, []);
        return;
    }
    */
    //var myList:Array = {value: "message", caption: "Caption to user", meta: "Type shown", score: "I don't know"};

    var testing:Boolean = false;

    if (testing) {
        callback(autoCompleteErrorMessage, [{value:"addedToStage"},{value:"added"},{value:"adding"}]);
    }
    else {
        callback(autoCompleteErrorMessage, attributes);
    }
}


protected function cursorChangeHandler(event:Event):void {

    var qname:QName = getQNameFromCursorPosition(ace.row, ace.column);
    if (qname==null) {
        if (attributes.length) {
            attributes = [];
        }
        return;
    }

    if (qname) { 
        attributes = getSuggestionListFromObject(classObject);
        autoCompleteErrorMessage = null;
        lastSelectedQName = qname;
    }
}


public static var XML_TAG_NAME:String       = "meta.tag.tag-name.xml";
public static var XML_TAG_OPEN:String       = "meta.tag.punctuation.tag-open.xml";
public static var XML_TAG_CLOSE:String      = "meta.tag.punctuation.tag-close.xml";
public static var XML_ATTRIBUTE_NAME:String = "entity.other.attribute-name.xml";

public function getQNameFromCursorPosition(row:int, column:int):QName {
    var token:Object;
    var line:String;
    var type:String;
    var value:String;
    var found:Boolean;
    var qname:QName;

    for (; row > -1; row--) {
        line = ace.getLine(row);
        column = line.length;

        for (; column>-1; column--) {
            token = ace.getTokenAt(row, column);
            type = token ? token.type : "";

            if (type==XML_TAG_NAME) {
                value = token.value;
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if (found) break;
    }

    if (found) {
        qname = new QName("", value);
    }

    return qname;
}
```

The `getQNameFromCursorPosition()` method is fragile and I'm looking into a new method using the `jumpToMatching()` method.